# char ** should I malloc size of (char*) or size of char * string length?

Tags: c, string

I have a dynamic struct like so:

```
struct network {
    int count;
    char** ips;
}
```

If I know each string array is 16 bytes (ie. `INET_ADDRSTRLEN`) because they are IPv4 addresses, does it matter if I allocate with `sizeof(char*) * count` or `sizeof(char) * INET_ADDRSTRLEN * count`?

For example:

```
// n is a pointer to a network

n->ips = realloc(n->ips, sizeof(char*) * n->count);

for (int i =0; i< n->count; i++){
    n->ips[i] = malloc(INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    strcpy(n->ips[i], "127.0.0.1");
}
```

OR

```
n->ips = realloc(n->ips, sizeof(char) * INET_ADDRSTRLEN * n->count);

for (int i =0; i< n->count; i++){
    n->ips[i] = malloc(INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    strcpy(n->ips[i], "127.0.0.1");
}
```

Also, if I do it the second way, do I need to do `n->ips[i] = malloc(INET_ADDRSTRLEN);`?

Comment: Yes, it matters which you use.  You'll need to allocate an array of pointers, and also the data for the pointers to point at.  The data space might be a single allocation or multiple smaller allocations; you can set the pointers appropriately either way.  (A single allocation is probably better, as long as you're careful.) This is controlled by the `char **` type (notation).  If you were playing with `char (*ips)[16];`, the answer would be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ips points to an array of char *, so its buffer must be a multiple of sizeof(char *), not a multiple of sizeof(char).

Answer (score 1):

For reliability, the better one would be to use the idiomatic form of `malloc`/`realloc`:

```
n->ips = malloc(n->count * sizeof(*n->ips))); // n * sizeof(element)
```

This way, if the type of `ips` will change some day, you don't need to fix the code in every occurence of memory allocation function.

As a rule of thumb, always check the result of memory allocation function, because it might fail.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, ips is a pointer to pointers to char. So, when you allocate memory for it, you need to allocate space for pointers to char. This means that your first example is the correct fit.

Footnote: I am assuming that someplace else you have code to initialize ips to a value like NULL. Doing a `realloc` on random junk is a bad idea. If this is not an actual reallocation consider using `malloc` instead. If this IS a true reallocation, then you have a memory leak since the count pointers in the array are being replaced with new buffers without freeing the previous buffers.

Finally, I think you need to malloc INET_ADDRSTRLEN+1 to reserve space for the trailing null character.

Comment: 16 = 3 + '.' + 3 + '.' + 3 + '.' + 3 + '\0'; the extra `+ 1` isn't necessary because `INET_ADDRSTRLEN` is designed to make it unnecessary.